# How to connect to Oracle 12c Database using cx_Oracle

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle12c, cx-oracle

```
sqlplus sys/Oracle_1@pdborcl as sysdba;
```

i'm using this command to connect to Oracle 12c from Command Prompt.
How can i connect to the db using cx_Oracle. I'm new to Oracle DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the equivalent of the sqlplus command line that you posted:

```
import cx_Oracle

connect_string = "sys/Oracle_1@pdborcl"
con = cx_Oracle.connect(connect_string,mode=cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)
```

I tried it with a non-container database and not with a pdb so I can't verify that it would work with a pdb. You may not want to connect as sys as sysdba unless you know that you need that level of security.

Bobby

Comment: Thanks Bobby.. Got it.

Comment: Having an issue looking for guidance... it seems to work I get no error but my resultSet is empty and when i run insert command they arent added to the table.....

Answer (score 3):

You can find the documentation here [cx_Oracle docs](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection.html)

To query the database, use the below algorithm

```
import cx_Oracle

dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, sid) 
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(dsn,mode = cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)
query = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE"
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
resultSet=cursor.fetchall()
connection.close()
```

The above code works to fetch data from MYTABLE connecting to the above dsn.
Better to go through cx_Oracle docs.

Comment: This answer shows using the very, very long obsolete SID usage which will trick many people.  The preferred way is dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, service_name="yourservicename")

Comment: Hi Shankar when i use SID its failing.. i used the above method by @Bobby Durret.  Using SID will fail in Oracle 12c i think, instead we can use " service_name = "pdborcl" " instead of SID while making "dsn"

Comment: Thanks Christopher your method is working for me. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Having an issue looking for guidance... it seems to work I get no error but my resultSet is empty and when i run insert command they arent added to the table.....